# Htacces Apache END Flag alternative

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wrote a small framework (PHP) for small projects, which in all should be redirected to index.php?path=$1, except the defined paths. With the END flag this is not problematic. But the END flag exists still since Apache 2.3 and the script should work also on apache 2.2 servers.

Has anyone an idea how I can realize this without the END flag?

```
RewriteEngine on

# Define static redicts
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)$ public/image/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^css/(.+)$ public/css/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)$ public/js/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/core/(.+)$ core/lib/js/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/(.+)$ public/lib/js/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cache/(.+)$ public/cache/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ public/download/$1 [END,QSA]

# Define custom redicts
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?path=index.php&page=$1 [END,QSA]

# Define all other redicts
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since all of your rules end with the `END` flag, you more or less want to prevent any looping of the rewrite engine at all. To accomplish the same thing without using the `END` flag, replace them all with the `L` flag and add a passthrough rule at the *beginning*:

```
RewriteEngine on

# pass-through if another rewrite rule has been applied already
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Define static redicts
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)$ public/image/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^css/(.+)$ public/css/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)$ public/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/core/(.+)$ core/lib/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lib/js/(.+)$ public/lib/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cache/(.+)$ public/cache/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ public/download/$1 [L,QSA]

# Define custom redicts
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?path=index.php&page=$1 [L,QSA]

# Define all other redicts
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```