# htaccess canonical URL subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the same problem as [htaccess - canonical URL when redirecting to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243449/htaccess-canonical-url-when-redirecting-to-subdirectory), but the solution there appears to use a hardcoded host name in the htaccess file which I can't do.

The following is in my htaccess file in the root directory which works fine for redirecting all requests into the `/public` directory with the exception of `node_modules`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   # Allow node_modules
   RewriteRule ^node_modules($|/) - [L]
   # Rewrite everything to public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

However I realize that the pages can be accessed through two different URLs, for example:

- `https://localhost/application1/foo/books.php`
- `https://localhost/application1/public/foo/books.php`

How do I either prevent the second one (ideally) or have it redirect to the first one?

I tried various RewriteCond statements with `%{THE_REQUEST}` but they turned out to be infinite loops. As mentioned above this needs to be hostname-agnostic as the application runs on different environments.

#### Update

I tried @SuperDuperApps answer below with the following in my .htaccess, which seemed to make no difference:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^node_modules($|/)
RewriteCond $1 !^public($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L,R=404]
```

After enabling `RewriteLogLevel 3` in my dev server, this is what appears when I access a file with `/public` in the URL:

```
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:52:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d6a5d58/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/public/] pass through /var/www/html/application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js
```

And this is when I access the same file without `/public` in the URL (desired behaviour):

```
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/application1/common -> /var/www/html/application1/common/assets/js/nav.min.js
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/application1/common/assets/js/nav.min.js -> common/assets/js/nav.min.js
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'common/assets/js/nav.min.js'
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] rewrite 'common/assets/js/nav.min.js' -> 'public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js'
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] add per-dir prefix: public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js -> /var/www/html/application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js -> /application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d684738/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/] internal redirect with /application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
192.168.33.1 - - [27/Jan/2017:22:48:45 --0500] [localhost/sid#7f4a0d1d2cf0][rid#7f4a0d676688/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/application1/public/] pass through /var/www/html/application1/public/common/assets/js/nav.min.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with two separate files.

#### .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   # Allow node_modules
   RewriteRule ^node_modules($|/) - [L]
   # Rewrite everything to public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

#### .htaccess inside public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # pass-through if another rewrite rule has been applied already
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
    RewriteRule .* - [S=1] # Skip the next rule
    RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

    # ...additional rules here as needed
</IfModule>
```

[`[L]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) can have been used instead of [`[S=1]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) in the second file if there are no additional rules.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324233/htacces-apache-end-flag-alternative) gave me the idea with "pass-through if redirect".

Also thanks to @SuperDuperApps for the debugging hint with RewriteLogLevel and the original answer with the [`[END]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) flag that may have worked if I had Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Allow node_modules
RewriteCond $1 !^node_modules($|/)
# Rewrite everything to public except public
RewriteCond $1 !^public($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
# 404 diret access to public
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect :/

Comment: Please be more specific, what did you try and what happened?

Comment: I tried changing the block in my htaccess file to the one in your answer and it continued to redirect everything into `public`, but accessing `public` itself wasn't prevented. I had to change `END` to `L` as I'm on Apache 2.2, but I don't think that would have made a difference.

Comment: And the block is in your .htaccess file? Do you have access to the server config? If so please add level 3 rewrite logging to the VirtualHost and post the trace when you visit /public/. You can do that with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23295792/2493235).